# How do you customize the look of UIKit objects?

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, uikit

I know that there are properties in some of the UIKit items like tintColor that you can use, but is it okay to subclass these items in order to make your application look a certain way. I only ask because I know that the classes in UIKit as well as other frameworks Apple provides are supposed to be highly optimized and I wouldn't want to lose that performance.

Answer (score 1):

In iOS 5 Apple added features to customize UIControls. See this http://www.raywenderlich.com/4344/user-interface-customization-in-ios-5